# How many years could notebook computers and phones be stored in a closed bunker/vault and still operational when found?

Tags: internal-consistency, post-apocalypse, computers

The idea is for some people in a post-apocalyptic future to find these bunkers/vaults and be able to turn on the computers and charge the cellphones. How many years could the equipment last if they were stored in very good conditions (no sun light, no humidity, all covered in plastic or inside boxes)? 10 years? 100 years?

There are already some related questions ([this one specific about cars](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/81560/for-how-long-after-an-apocalypse-would-modern-cars-remain-usable)), but in most of them the objects where abandoned in the environment or left behind without being properly stored.

Comment: Can the devices be plugged in to wall power? As Separatrix mentioned, the batteries in these devices will most definitely be the first things to go. Even with a dead battery, most modern devices can still function when provided wall power (or bypassed rather easily to function with the appropriate DC voltage being provided otherwise).

Comment: For the cellphones, if you intend to use them as **phones** (as opposed to use them as miniature computers, e.g. using data that is stored on them), then the networks they are compatible with will probably be the first to go.

Comment: You may get rid of the issue by providing these devices with solid state batteries rather than the classic LiPo. They are still in development but it wouldn't be that sci-fi to make them available to some gov agency. That would have the benefit of being a pretty unknown tech without many info available about life span

Comment: One thing that the answers below haven't mentioned: the screens. LED and CRT displays will last forever if protected from dust. LCD screens will not, and I suspect, neither will the various OLEDs. I've seen [LCD screens grow mould](https://www.ifixit.com/Answers/View/356731/Fungus+on+LCD+screen) if not regularly aired.

Comment: Definitely related: [How long can an abandoned, semi-sheltered computer remain bootable?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/5093/29)

Comment: If they where designed for long-term storage, the answers could be different. The problems @nzaman mentions could be solved with the Right packaging (Oxigen-free and steril atmosphere)

Comment: How much modification is acceptable?  Basically, if you could replace the batteries with a technology intended for longer shelf life, you’d get a very different answer.

Comment: [This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jCCTps.jpg) was 77 years ago. Even if the Z3 is fully functional today, would anyone be able to use it? Would you be able to use a computer which is just a shell and no UI? I think the rapid technological improvement is - ironically - the main reason notebooks wouldn't be operational after a few decades at most, no matter how solid the hardware is: There's no-one that remembers how to use that stuff.

Comment: @Narusan That's a very good point, but I think that today's computers interface are much more intuitive, specially in devices like a tablet. I think that someone with patience (and maybe some basic written instructions) can find out how to use it. That is probably not true for the example you gave.

Comment: @Narusan Actually, I'd suspect that with user's, programmer's (not that there would be much difference between the two), and service manuals - assuming, obviously, that one is able to read them - something like the Z3 might actually be *easier* than a tablet to use for its originally intended purpose after many years in storage. Yes, it *looks* rather intimidating to the uninitiated, but so does [a Boeing 787 cockpit](https://www.wired.com/2011/10/cockpit-tour-of-all-nippon-airways-boeing-787-dreamliner/) (in which *tons* of complexity is actually hidden, e.g. in the flight management system).

Comment: As for *"There's no-one that remembers how to use that stuff."*, don't forget that there's a large, widespread interest in [retrocomputing.se]. Sure, that might not be primarily computers from the 1940s, but you'll find plenty of people working with the real thing from around 1980. That's the better part of 40 years ago. With manuals, those systems aren't harder to use now than they were back then.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

There are three really big problem components for long term storage of computer hardware, batteries, flash memory, and electrolytic capacitors.  While there are other components that can fail in long-term storage, most of them can be kept working if the storage environment is ideal.  These three, however, will pretty reliably fail after a reasonably short period of time independent of the environment they are kept in.  In particular:

- Batteries: Varies, but generally not very long.  Most batteries have a shelf life of at best a few years when left unused.  The CMOS RTC battery in most computers won't be much of an issue barring some potentially weird configurations that rely on firmware settings.  The batteries in phones or laptops however are another story.  For those, you'll be lucky if they work at all after about 5 years of being unused.  From a safety perspective, you should also be replacing (or at least reconditioning) any batteries in such a device before attempting to use it, failure there tends to be catastrophic and very dangerous.  In some cases, you *might* be able to get away with having a really exotic type of battery that can safely be stored for long periods of time (Silver-Air batteries come to mind, but they're expensive, not rechargeable, and still only last at most a few years).  You might also make things better by storing the device with the battery fully discharged (most rechargeable batteries have a longer shelf-life if stored discharged), but that probably also won't extend things by much.
- Flash storage: Theoretically indefinite if there's no hard radiation, but it won't retain data past a few years without special efforts taken to do so.  Flash memory is insanely durable when not being used.  About the only things that can reliably make it stop working are long term exposure to hard radiation, extreme thermal stress, extreme heat, or just plain physically destroying it.  However, it's actually not really all that good for long term data storage.  The reason for this relates to how flash memory works.  In short, flash memory stores data by trapping an electrical charge on an otherwise electrically isolated bit of conductive material.  Doing this requires pushing electrons across a layer of insulating material, which degrades the insulating material over time (this is why flash memory is write-limited), causing the electrical charge to slowly leak out.  For flash memory seeing active usage, this isn't much of an issue as things will get rewritten before it becomes an issue.  For flash memory in archival storage however, this puts an upper limit on how long your data will last.  For good quality SLC NAND flash, this limit is estimated to be somewhere around 5 years.  For the cheap MLC NAND flash used in most devices these days, it's usually only 2-3 years.  There's not really any practical way around this except not using flash memory, but most forms of storage media do have some type of long-term degradation they have to deal with.
- Electrolytic capacitors: At most 15 years.  These are mostly used for power handling in computers and other devices.  The issue with them is that they use a gel as one of the two electrodes, and if this gel dries out or leaks out, the capacitor will stop working (and if it leaks, it may damage other components when you try to power on the device).  Even if kept in otherwise perfect conditions, the sealing material will deteriorate over time, which for current designs puts a functional upper limit of about 15 years on their life expectancy.  You can obviously work around this by just not using electrolytic capacitors (and some phones don't for exactly this reason), but it's non-trivial to figure out if an arbitrary system uses them or not, and most of the alternatives come with their own issues.

Comment: You might also make things better by storing the device with the battery fully discharged — this is not precise. There is a lowest charge that allows safe recharge. 0% on your phone means this level + safety margin, not real 0 charge left. And batteries tend to lose charge on their own when unused, so more years = more safety margin you need. More safety margin = faster deterioration, and finding the sweet spot is tricky.

Comment: @Mołot I suspect it also depends on the exact battery design and charging circuit.  Most of design's I've seen actually recommend storing the battery discharged as far as the device will let you when you plan on storing it for more than a few months without usage.

Comment: "as the device will let you" - that's what I'm talking about. Devices have their safety margins in place. But try storing one for a year or two - high chance you'll go past safety and protection circuit will simply refuse to load it.

Comment: @lupino if the devices were deliberately built to last, the story could be quite different. If you are willing to make significant sacrifices and accept high cost, both in R&D and materials - to begin with, optimize for durability, not performance. Do not use electrolytic capacitors. Store read-only data in ROM. Do not use batteries, instead use some other kind of power source as well as instructions on how to create a power source from scratch. Etc etc.Use simple LED character display and speakers instead of graphical displays. Etc etc.

Comment: Giving “15 years _at most_” for electrolytic capacitors is a bit pessimistic. I have used lots of devices containing elkos that were decades old, mostly without problems. Yes, there's a risk of them blowing out, but in a post-apocalyptic world there are more severe risks... (Though, I would assume that these old devices had more rugged, because less cost- and size-optimised capacitors than modern computers would.)

Comment: @leftaroundabout 15 years is a pretty standard quote from most of the places that actually make electrolytic capacitors.  They can of course last longer, but I'm quoting here what I've seen most places when searching for expected life spans.  I've also used stuff older than that that used them, but I haven't done so enough to say with confidence that the manufacturers are wrong in their estimates.

Comment: @AustinHemmelgarn I don't say 15 years not a good figure, I just wouldn't say “at most 15”. It is good advice to replace elkos after 15 years if you don't want to risk a failing one damage something else, but if you have no choice (and don't really care about damaging the rest of the device, since it's worthless else anyway) then you will _probably_ be able to use them for quite a bit longer.

Comment: Re batteries: You might be better off removing the batteries entirely and instead providing technical specifications for new batteries on paper (or something more durable than paper).  Of course, if recovering society could be post-apocalyptic or otherwise primitive, this may not work.  But at that point you also have to contend with language and cultural barriers, which are substantially harder problems.

Answer (score 26):

There are two primary parts you need to consider the shelf life of for these devices

- Magnetic storage
- The battery

The general theme of this is that while magnetic storage shelf life can be [measured in decades](https://www.pcworld.com/article/2984597/storage/hard-core-data-preservation-the-best-media-and-methods-for-archiving-your-data.html). LiPo battery shelf life is [measured in years](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/150818/shelf-life-of-a-lithium-polymer-battery).

The real limiting factor here is the LiPo batteries. They don't like being overcharged, or fully discharged, or shocked, or not used, or overused. Their general reaction to all of these things [is to explode](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/230155/why-is-there-so-much-fear-surrounding-lipo-batteries).

So while visually they may be in pristine condition, the chances of being able to get any of these devices to run is minimal after anything over a decade of storage.

---

There's an extra factor here that needs to be considered

- Solid state storage

Unfortunately this is currently an unknown quantity. As a fairly new and rapidly changing technology, lifespan estimates range from decay starting in only 7 days when left unpowered to lasting over 300 years with steady use.

Comment: +1, the batteries, they will degrade within a decade no matter how well stored. I'd also add mobile phones won't call anywhere without cellular towers and computers that have electricity, and in a post-apoc world, I doubt you have the full electrical grid up and powering everything. If you do, get those manufacturing plants running to manufacture new batteries!

Comment: The storage on these devices is solid state, not magnetic. Still good answer because the Li batteries are the big issue.

Comment: @pojo-guy, the trouble is that solid state drives are too new for there to be real data. I've seen estimated values from over 300years of solid use to 7 days when unpowered.

Comment: It is possible that the batteries could be taken out and a wall socket hooked up to solar panels could be used.

Comment: I always figured that things like batteries and various other parts would be something that you would plan your "hopefully long surviving" bunker  to be able to manufacture. along with some form of power source to charge them

Comment: The secret to the SSD is that it used electrical arcing to melt metal to create and break physical connections. I routinely leave SSS' s unpowered for weeks at a time with no issues. You are correct that were don't know the upper limit, but it is easily longer than the lifespan of the Li batteries - I have gone through multiple sets of batteries but my ssd's are still going strong

Comment: 'The secret to the SSD is that it used electrical arcing to melt metal to create and break physical connections' well, I'm pretty sure that the mechansim is a bit different than that, eg. electrons trapped, (or not), between insulated gates in a transistor.  If the SSD data could be refreshed at intervals to mitigate occasional electrons tunneling their way to freedom, the lifetime could be very long. especially if the drive has a much larger capacity than the data and multiple copies can be stored/checked,

Comment: If battery failure is an issue, it might be worth also considering what would happen with the internal BIOS battery.

Comment: @SSight3 The CMOS (RTC) battery is largely inconsequential. You'll have to reset the clock, and may need to set some other parameters, before the system will boot properly after having been disconnected from power, but that's plenty doable. As K. Morgan discusses, it may actually be better to remove the battery!

Comment: The Bios is also relies on the same technology as a SSD. It will loose its programming and the computer won´t even boot. If you want a long-term computer you need optic memory like specially produced CD-ROM´s

Comment: @αCVn On a long scale, I'm wondering if the battery would possibly leak or corrode (such as leaking battery acid which then damages internals).

Comment: @SSight3 I believe that question has come up on [retrocomputing.se] a few times, in different forms. Certainly there is a question about [What precautions to take when powering on old computer for the first time in years](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/q/2848/357).

Comment: @αCVn I'm only mentioning so original answer can be improved. That kind of link should ideally be added to the above answer.

Comment: Not necessarily. I worked in a military scrap yard and our warehouse saw plenty of old laptops  that were a decade plus old. The batteries are not necessarily connected, and they are not in themselves unstable enough to blow up. Windows 95 system that worked fine in 2015.

Comment: Surely millions of people have left their SSDs unpowered for more than a week by now. If the data loss was possible in such a brief time frame, this would be well-known.

Comment: @Daniel But then again, the processor has no idea how to operate a CD-ROM, that's also programmed in BIOS. Also, there's a small flash memory inside the CPU proper, storing its firmware. When that's gone, you have a bigger problem.

Comment: @IMil, minor data loss on SSDs is well known, but mostly it's below a noticeable threshold. Most people never fully power them off and certainly not for long periods.

Comment: @The Vee: Just what I said - but that´s because it´s designed that way.

Comment: You might be exaggerating a bit on LiPo batteries - No, when stored only, they don't tend to explode. They will very likely just die. It is rather that batteries tend to leak over time, destroying viable parts of your stored equipment with leaking acid.

Comment: @tofro the fun bit is that yes, they just die when stored. But if you then try to charge them again, that's when they explode

Answer (score 8):

One more cause of failure to note are “Tin Whiskers”.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whisker_(metallurgy)

At present, any lead-free solder used will form tin/zinc/silver whiskers at some unpredictable time in the future.  These hairs are a few micrometers across and once started can grow as fast as 1mm per year.  Eventually the whiskers will bridge pins and traces on the circuit board and destroy the device.  There has been a large amount of research into using conformal coatings to prevent this growth, but the massive pressure these growths generate in tiny pinpoint locations has been able to eventually penetrate or lift all coatings that have been tested.

This brings up an interesting side of your question.  Electronics built before the mid-2000s may not have this type of failure for centuries, while electronics built after the lead soldier ban are unlikely to last much beyond 20 years.  However, safety critical and space flight circuits are currently excepted from the ban.  This means computers in cars, airplanes, satellites, and power plants are allowed to use lead soldier and will not suffer from this problem.

Comment: Allowed to, but sometimes do not use lead. (Source - I worked at an industrial and train equipments manufacturer.)

Comment: With whiskers that fine, a brief wash with a weak acid may be sufficient to 'revive' them.

Answer (score 5):

Another issue to consider is the overall system aspect of cell phones. They don't work without a cell tower network, including functioning computers to keep track of everything. So cell phones simply won't work at all once the external tech has died.

Comment: They would work as portable computers. I read a trilogy (can't remember the titles or author at the moment) where one key plot point was a character who, when on an alternate timeline mixed-up Earth of sorts (it gets complicated...) has essentially a very-smart-phone with a huge database of information, so that even without any cell phone network at all (effectively the only phone on Earth) it is still extremely useful as a computer.

Comment: manassehkatz is correct, you don't need any kind of network link to access the data stored on most computers and smart-phones, you only need it to access the network.

Comment: @AustinHemmelgarn But most smart-phones really don't have that much data on them (yay "cloud"). A database like manassehkatz referenced would have had to be deliberately and explicitly installed.

Comment: @T.J.L.It really depends on what data you care about.  Many people have quite a few photos and a reasonable amount of music on their smartphones.

Comment: Well, I could make a pretty cheap "cell" network. Phones can wifi call. You can get a couple of fiber to ethernet converters that can work up to 60km and they are only a couple hundred bucks each. Install a wifi router, plug the converter to it. Tap into an existing fiber line or run you own up to 60km. Put the same thing on the other end. Power them with solar panels. Add nodes if needed.

Answer (score 3):

I would think that any computer equipment (PC, notebook, phone) would last pretty well, as long as:

- Any battery (including e.g. a coin-cell motherboard battery) was removed
- It didn't rust (temperature and humidity were low)
- Doesn't rely on EPROM holding state (it will degrade in a decade or so)
- The plastics didn't degrade too much
- Any capacitors didn't leak

So if the computers were intentionally stored for long-term survival, and there were instructions on how to put them back together, build new batteries, etc. then they could last for.. let's say multiple decades but probably not much longer than 100-150 years.

As for any data, the storage medium would need to be carefully considered.

- USB sticks, flash media. - maybe 10 years if you're lucky
- Other solid state media - lasts a few decades ([Here's one that supposedly works for 100 years though](https://www.pcworld.com/article/199672/sandisks_sd_card_can_store_data_for_100_years.html))
- Magnetic tape - [about the same](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Media_preservation)
- Spinning-rust hard drives - [maybe 100 years](https://superuser.com/questions/284427/how-much-time-until-an-unused-hard-drive-loses-its-data), allowing for some data loss and degradation of the moving parts
- Optical storage  - Archive-grade BluRays [claim](https://www.zdnet.com/article/the-1000-year-dvd-is-here/) [up to 1000 years](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Years-Archival-Verbatim-M-Disc-Blu-ray/dp/B01B99WUR6).

Comment: With respect to "any battery" - in addition to the primary batteries, which are easily removable on most laptops & phones, but most definitely not on all of them, there are often smaller batteries (e.g., CR2032 or similar for clock) that (a) often require disassembly to get to them for removal and (b) are sometimes not designed to be easily removable even once you find them. Those smaller batteries can degrade - e.g., leak - over time too, which is definitely a consideration for any > 10 years situation.

Comment: Um, no UV radiation does not corrupt _EEPROMS_, it _erases_ _EPROMS_ (which are different and largely unused anymore), but they have to be have it directly shining through the quartz window on the packaging of the chip, which would be hidden by the case of whatever the chip is in.

Comment: Also, flash memory (including most solid state media) is good for only a couple of years without prophylactic rewrites, magnetic tape can last longer than you probably think if kept in ideal conditions, and optical media actually does degrade over the course of a few decades.

Comment: @Austin Hemmelgam: Thanks for the EEPROM comment; I was actually thinking about how the BIOS would survive but confused myself.
Regarding your other comments, I stand by my estimates. I will edit in some more links to justify them.

Comment: @manassehkatz: Yes indeed, any battery (which is why I mentioned the motherboard battery)

Comment: Oops. I somehow missed that you **did** already mention the motherboard battery. But my main point is those batteries are often very hard to remove/replace on a laptop. Desktop (unless soldered) - takes < 1 minute (mostly to remove the case screws).

Comment: Well I'm assuming a best-case scenario that someone has deliberately selected/prepared the computers for long-term survival, so I wouldn't expect the time to remove the battery to be a huge issue.

Comment: @AustinHemmelgarn, the durability of solid-state storage depends strongly on temperature.  At one extreme, if you write data while the device is hot, then store it in a cold environment, you can get a century or more of reliable storage.  At the other extreme, writing cold and storing hot, the data will be lost in a matter of days.  Under typical conditions (write warm, store at room temperature), data retention is around 5-20 years.

Comment: @Mark Good point, although actually having the kind of a temperature differential from write to storage that's necessary to achieve really good long term retention is not exactly something that can be done easily by most people.

Comment: Hard drives tend to have bearings that stick after a few years non-use.  Rotate your stock.

Answer (score 3):

If the devices were deliberately built to last, the story could be quite different.

If you are willing to make significant sacrifices and accept high cost, both in R&D and materials - to begin with, optimize for durability, not performance.

- Do not use electrolytic capacitors or rechargeable batteries.
- Store read-only data in old school ROM. (Not EPROM even, ROM.)
- Make all circuits essentially space grade, so not even accumulated background radiation can flip something.
- Do not use batteries, instead use some other kind of power source as well as instructions on how to create a power source from scratch.
- Provide dry batteries (non-rechargeable) for boot-strapping in the first phase.
- Wet batteries but with chemicals stored separately in large vats with instructions on how to activate them?
- Use simple LED character displays and small speakers for output instead of relying on normal, complex bitmapped displays.
- Provide extensive documentation on all systems, including physical paper (or plastic) on *everything*
- Build the same system with different technologies in several versions, from discrete transistors up to ICs with everything in between, so a society can bootstrap and make replicas in ever increasing sophistication.

and so on...

a bit on a tangent but I thought it was a cool idea. Like a Rosetta stone for computing.

Answer (score 1):

Atmel ATMega series microcontrollers give 100 year data retention guarantee. This is at regular shelf around 25C. Under better conditions they can last longer and even better performing devices can be built for the purpose. I can see a computer system that will be able to work after several 100 years. LEDs do last for a very long time. Even while working non-stop, I have seen LEDs working for 20+ years. Thus a simple (say 200x100) LED screen could easily last several centuries. Just protect everything from rusting and temperature swings.

Unfortunately, batteries will not last that long. There are lithium batteries that can last for 40 years, that is the best I could find. So it would be an issue to power these devices. The best bet could be a mechanical device that can be cranked to supply power to a low power device. Of course this mechanical device should be stored in an airtight storage.

Answer (score 1):

Just today, may 26, 2022. I turned on a zenith laptop computer that was made in the late 80s and seemed to function as I should have back then. From what I can tell, this is probably the first time it's been turned on in 30 years. Granted, it didn't have batteries, and it's slow and the screen sucks, but as long as the capacitors dont leak, and the HD doesnt bind up, they may work as if not a day has gone by.